# firebase realtime database reload after transactions in for-loop are done

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code.

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          let brand = array[i];
          // handle analytics
          database.ref("brands/" + brand).transaction(function (post) {
            if (post) {
              if (post.followers != null) {
                post.followers++;
              } else {
                post.followers = 1;
              }
            }
            return post;
          });
}

// once all is done, trigger a reload
// window.location.reload();
```

Basically I am handling some analytics with transactions in a for-loop. However, I wish to do a `window.location.reload` after **all** the transactions are completed in the for-loop. (I believe if I trigger the reload immediately after the for-loop, all the transactions may not have been completed and will be interrupted by the reload.)

I'm not too sure how to approach this (with async, await, chaining  promises etc), so I'm wondering what's the most direct solution for such a problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know how many transactions you need to run (`array.length`), you can count how many transactions have finished, and then reload the window after the last one:

```
let doneCount = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  let brand = array[i];
  database.ref("brands/" + brand).transaction(function (post) {
    if (post) {
      if (post.followers != null) {
        post.followers++;
      } else {
        post.followers = 1;
      }
    }
    return post;
  }, function(error, committed, snapshot) {
    if (doneCount++ == array.length) {
      window.location.reload();
    }
  });
}
```

Also see the documentation for [`runTransaction`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction).

---

But since a few months, there is a much simpler way to do this: using the `ServerValue.increment()` operator. In fact, with that, you can combine the entire loop into a single update statement:

```
let updates = {};
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  let brand = array[i];
  updates[`brands/${brand}] = firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(1);
}
database.ref().update(updates);
```

Much simpler!

Comment: May I ask what is `let updates = P{;`, was that a typo?

Comment: Also, with the simpler method, i seem to be receiving this new error. `TypeError: _plugins_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.firebase.database.ServerValue.increment is not a function`

Comment: also i believe there is a mistake in the first solution, `doneCount++` should be placed outside the if-condition instead of inside the if-condition

Comment: 1) The `let updates = P{;` was a typo/shift-left indeed. Fixed now. 2) For the missing import, check what version you are on. Here's the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue#increment) for that function. 3) I'm pretty sure this is correct with the counter. But if moving it works for you, then go for it.